# Multiple Bool with onTapGesture in Combined Text views

Tags: ios, swift, textview, swiftui

We can create combined text views (not line by line) using map and reduce functions.

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var boolArr = [false, false, true, true, false]

   var body: some View {
      (0...boolArr.count).map {
                Text("\($0)")
                }.reduce(Text(""), +)
   }
}
```

I want to underline specific text if we tap on the text not all texts. For example, if I tap on text "1", it underlines it. If I tap again, it removes underline. Not all texts underline and remove all underlines, only specific text on which I tap. The following approaches show me Cannot `convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'WritableKeyPath<_, _>'`

```
(1...boolArr.count).map {
   Text(" \($0) ").underline(self.$boolArr[$0])
   }.reduce(Text(""), +)
   .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
   self.$boolArr[$0] ? false: true
}
```

Why $0 is not working? And, which way will be working?

Comment: your .onTapGesture will be on one Text -> the reduced Text (which is just one UI component), which contents might be "12345". So how shall it know which letter you tapped? And your "example" will crash anyway because index out of bounds because arrays will start with index 0.

Answer (score 0):

and here is my solution for you. Hope it helps

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var boolArr = [false, false, true, true, false]

    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            ForEach([1,2,3,4,5], id: \.self) { number  in
                Text("\(number)")
                    .underline(self.boolArr[number - 1])
                    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                        self.boolArr[number - 1].toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```